# Getting a "scope" error in C++

Tags: c++

I am getting the error "Error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope," but I included `<iostream>`, which was the solution that was given for similar problems in my research.  My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){

    Sally so;
    Cout << "omg wtf is this on my shoe" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I've fixed your formatting, and also added the `#include <iostream>` you claimed to have included since you forgot to put that in your code.

Comment: std::cout not Cout

Comment: `cout` needs to be lowercase, and it's inside of the `std` namespace. This would be covered in any tutorial or example.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm new to c++ and it can be very confusing.

Answer (score 5):

1. Its `cout` not `Cout`, notice the case difference.
2. `cout` is in the namespace `std`. In order to use it you need to resolve the namespace with `std::`, so use `std::cout << ...`.
3. As much as people will tell you to just do `using namespace std`, **dont**. For more info, [see *Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?*.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

1. You are writing "Cout" not "cout" - C++ is case sensitive, so those two are not the same thing.
2. You should write `std::cout` since the `cout` stream lives in the `std` namespace.
3. The same goes for `endl` which should be `std::endl`.

You *could* avoid writing `std::` by using `using namespace std;` but I wouldn't advice it - it pulls all of the namespace into the current scope which may not hurt for a trivial program *will* bite for a more complex one (at the very least, don't do it in headers).

Just do this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    Sally so;
    std::cout << "omg wtf is this on my shoe" << std::endl;
}
```

Btw; unless you know you want to flush the stream, prefer `'\n'` over `std::endl`.

Comment: Reminder:  another alternative is `using std::cout; using std::endl;`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Sally so;
    cout<<"the text"<<endl;
}
```

Hope it helps!!
Cheers

Comment: `using namespace std` is bad advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Please don't spread bad practices like `using namespace std;`.